# Operating system not found after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: grub2, partitioning, system-installation, 15.04

I had a Dell XPS with several Ubuntu-based distros installed on it (Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04 and Elementary OS Luna and Freya). Then I tried Antergos and installed it to one partition. After that, I could no longer boot from the SSD. I always get an "Operation System not found" error.

I tried recovering grub following this instructions http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

I also tried reinstalling from Freya and 15.04 live USB with no luck.

I'm about to completely wipe the whole SSD, but first I'd like to know if there's anything else I could try.

From the live USB, everything seems to work fine. I can see the partitions and update them with GParted. I installed the OS and everything installs with no errors.

Comment: what happened when you tried repairing from the live disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tryed to boot from USB and enter the terminal, and type this in:

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get -y install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it might work fine this way.

more info at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair