# System can't see main SSD?

Tags: boot, ssd, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my SSD, and after starting the PC yesterday, it would not boot. Two things stand out to me.

First, grub times out after 90s of waiting for device /dev/sda1, which is the system drive.

That means, that just afterwards it cannot find /media or Local File Systems.

Second, I am booted into emergency mode, and attempting to continue displays a red message saying:

`Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operating system not found after installing Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642056/operating-system-not-found-after-installing-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a spare USB drive available for now. The soonest I will be able to get one, is a few days from now, so I hope there is another way to fix the issue

Comment: You can use the USB drive you used to install Ubuntu 22.04. Boot from it and use the **Try Ubuntu** option.

Comment: That USB stick was the only one I had, and after trying it earlier today, I found that it's no longer working. I confirmed that on another computer with Windows installed too